# IIS - Windows Server 2019 - Permissions error

Tags: php, windows, iis, windows-server-2019

I have installed PHP 7.3 in my C:/php folder. Installed PHP Manager extension for IIS and transferred my website's files inside the root folder. I go to localhost/install to install the script, and I get the Installation Error **"uploads" folder must be writable.**

I've given Full Control permissions (by doing Sites -> Explore -> Right Click on Root folder) to IUSR, DefaultAppPool, IIS_IUSR but nothing, I still get the error. I don't know what to do more.

Comment: Try running IIS as an administrator.

Comment: Sorry, how this could help me where permissions are already set?